# C# xNet Post Request MultipartContent

Tags: c#, http-post

```
var Data = new MultipartContent()
                {
                    {new StringContent("id"), "21"},
                    {new StringContent("name"), "test"},
                    {new StringContent("brand"),""},                   
                };
```

Как отправить пустой параметр?Студия выдаёт исключение.

Comment: Куда отправить ? Какое исключение ? Расширьте вопрос. Но для начала попробуйте отправить пробел вместо пустой строки. А на адресате уже string.IsNullOrEmpty() проверять

Answer (score 1):

Скорей всего Вы не достаточно внимательно разглядели [пример](https://habrahabr.ru/post/146475/) использования указанной библиотеки. В коде Вы пытаетесь отправить значение без указания к какому параметру оно относится.

{new StringContent("brand"),""},

нужно так

{new StringContent(""), "brand"},